# How to achieve different formats for label and text in a subsection heading using titlesec

Tags: sectioning, xetex, formatting, fontspec, titlesec

How to get a different formatting for the label and text of a subsection using titlesec?

Reason: Italic numbers in the subsection heading hurts my eyes and should be avoided at all cost, Label of the subsection should be a normal roman while the text should be in italic

First I define the fonts for the section and subsection headings of my document using fontspec:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont[LetterSpace=16.0,Path=C:/fonts/]{LTe50383.pfb} %sectionfont in Sabon Roman
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont[Path=C:/fonts/]{LTe50384.pfb} %subsection font is Sabon Italic
```

After this I define the titleformats:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\sectionfont}{\thesection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}{}
```

Is it even possible to differ the formatting? As written in the titlesec manual:

> format is the format to be applied
>   to the whole title—label and text.
>   This part can contain vertical
>   material (and horizontal with some
>   shapes) which is typeset just after
>   the space above the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}{\sectionfont\thesubsection.}{1em}{}{}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: oohww.. I tried that before but then for some reason it didnt work, but now it did. Thanks for the fast reply.